# KnockoutJS + Advanced Checkbox Functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, knockout.js

This checkbox is advanced in that not only is it set based on existing data, but the page must also respond in several ways to the user changing the checkbox by manually checking or unchecking it.

Imagine you have a `murderCaseModel` with list of various `Witnesses` to a crime.

Here is a Fiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/maxgrr/j6fm7162/6/

The requirements are as follows:

**Already Done**

- If previous `witnesses` exist from the loaded data, set the `checked` status of the box on page load

  ```
  <input type='checkbox' data-bind='checked: numWitnesses() > 0'></input>
  ```
- Delete `Witness`
- Add `Witness`

**TODO**

Toggling the checkbox causes another area on the page to appear or disappear

- If it is toggled by the user to 'No'(unchecked) we make the witness display area INVISIBLE (ideally, remove from DOM) and delete all of the `Witness` objects.
- If it is toggled to 'Yes'(checked) we make the witness display area VISIBLE and make sure there is at least one `Witness` object ready to be filled out by the user.

This whole problem is very tricky to me and determining the auto value for the checkbox but also the user selected value for it it difficult to grasp. Any help is much appreciated. It's a cool functionality!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`computed`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) to make your `wereThereAnyWitnesses` field a little smarter:

```
self.wereThereAnyWitnesses = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
        return self.numWitnesses() > 0;
    },
    write: function(wereThereAnyWitnesses) {
        if (!wereThereAnyWitnesses && self.numWitnesses() > 0) {
            if (!confirm("Remove all current witnesses?"))
                return self.wereThereAnyWitnesses.notifySubscribers();
            else
                self.witnesses.removeAll();
        }

        if (wereThereAnyWitnesses && self.numWitnesses() == 0)
            self.addWitness();
        }
}, this);
```

And in your HTML:

```
<input type='checkbox' data-bind='checked: wereThereAnyWitnesses' />
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6fm7162/10/)

Comment: Incredible! You have gone above and beyond. Thank You, sincerely. The only part I don't understand from your solution is why you wrapped the `wereThereAnyWitnesses` computed value, the `intitialValue`, and the `value` in the `(function(){})();` code.

Comment: I used an IIFE (http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to create some sort of a private "backing-field" for the `computed`. Since the `computed` itself only exposes a read/write interface, I needed somewhere to store the actual value, and that is the `value` variable. However, I didn't want that variable to be available outside the scope of the `computed` because it needs to be accessed (and modified) solely by the `computed`. To achieve this goal, IIFE is the ultimate (and common) solution.

Comment: You're a pro! Thank you for the resource. Something I noticed about your solution, though, is that if a user unchecks the box and then presses "Add Witness", the checkbox does not respond to that. Do you know how we would complete the circle of responsiveness?

Comment: Apparently, there was no need for "the actual value" at all. See the updated answer and Fiddle

Comment: There we go. That's much more readable. You're a wizard! For those reading this in the future, the comments on this question can largely be ignored, except for the educational bit on IIFE's which is enlightening, regardless. To me, this solution appears to be elegant and complete. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery. First, make sure you have included jQuery libraries in you head tags. Just copy the following code in your head tags:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then, use the following code to see if the check box is checked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ($('#the_checkbox').is(":checked"))
{
  $('#the_textarea').hide();
}
</script>
```

And here is the input:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="the_checkbox" />
```